# Get labels from URIs from Dbpedia (Jena)

Tags: java, sparql, jena, dbpedia

I have been trying to get the labels or literal values using sparql query. The current query I have is a construct query. It has been working out quite correctly. I am using jena model to read get the resultset.

```
String queryString = "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>"
                + "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>"
                + "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"
                + "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"
                + "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>" + "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>"
                + "PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>" + "PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>"
                + "PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>" + "PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>"
                + "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>" + 
                "CONSTRUCT {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Karim_Benzema> ?p ?o} where {"
                + "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Karim_Benzema> ?p ?o BIND(datatype(?o) as ?dt) FILTER(IF(isliteral(?o) && !bound(?dt), langMatches(lang(?o),'en'), true))" +

        "OPTIONAL{?o rdfs:label ?label . FILTER(langMatches(lang(?label),'en'))}}";
        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);


        FileOutputStream oFile;
        try {
            oFile = new FileOutputStream("output4.ttl", false);
            Model result21 = qexec.execConstruct();
            result21.write(oFile, "TTL");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        qexec.close();
        FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader());
        //Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel("output4.xml", null, "RDF/XML");
        try {
            Model model=ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
            model.read(new FileInputStream("output4.ttl"),null,"TTL");


        StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements();
        try {
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Statement stmt = iter.next();
                Resource s = stmt.getSubject();
                Resource p = stmt.getPredicate();
                RDFNode o = stmt.getObject();
                //System.out.println(s.toString());
                //System.out.println(p.toString());
                System.out.println(o.toString());
                listOfString.add(o.toString());
            //  if(o.isLiteral()){System.out.println(o.asLiteral().getLexicalForm());} //else {System.out.println(o);}
                //System.out.println("");
            }
        } finally {
            if (iter != null)
                iter.close();
        }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The predicates and objects that I am retrieving are as follows:-

> http://dbpedia.org/property/nationalteam Portugal U15@en
>
> http://dbpedia.org/property/caps
>   196^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer
>
> http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type
>   http://schema.org/Person
>
> http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type
>   http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/FootballPlayer110101634
>
> http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type
>   http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/ManchesterUnitedF.C.Players
>
> http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs
>   http://sw.opencyc.org/concept/Mx4rpQzh81h_Ed-LXQAhm0kILA
>
> http://dbpedia.org/property/youthyears
>   1997^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer
>
> http://dbpedia.org/property/nationalteamUpdate
>   2015-09-07^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date
>
> http://dbpedia.org/property/nationalteam
>   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Portugal_national_under-17_football_team
>
> http://purl.org/voc/vrank#hasRank 5a1e723ab34fab6f86528369689e6f7f
>
> http://dbpedia.org/property/name Cristiano Ronaldo@en
>
> http://dbpedia.org/property/width
>   31.0^^http://dbpedia.org/datatype/perCent

How can I get the labels only or the values and not the URIs?

Update of the query according to AKSW:

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
CONSTRUCT {
<http://dbpedia.org/page/Cristiano_Ronaldo> ?p ?o
} 
WHERE {
<http://dbpedia.org/page/Cristiano_Ronaldo> ?p ?o BIND(datatype(?o) as ?dt) FILTER(IF(isliteral(?o) && !bound(?dt), langMatches(lang(?o),'en'), true))
OPTIONAL{?o rdfs:label ?label . FILTER(langMatches(lang(?label),'en'))}
}
```

Comment: Please clarify! What means "labels for values" and "labels for URIs"? In RDF you either have resources (identified by URIs) or literals (numbers, dates, string, etc.). (I omit blank nodes here for simplicity) So what is your question?

Comment: If I assume that you want only literals, then you could filter the RDFNode object `o` , i.e. `if(o.isLiteral()) {...}`

Comment: @AKSW: What I intend to get are predicates like "Nationalteam" and objects like "Portugal".

Comment: Ok, so to be more precise, what you want is "only the triples in which the object is a literal". If you read it like this, it's quite obvious what to do: i) as I already said, if you want to print only those, use `if(o.isLiteral()) {...}`  ii) if you want those triples even only in the model, adapt the SPARQL query and add a filter `FILTER(isLiteral(?o))`.

Comment: 1) Yes if you see my query, I am already having a filter for literal objects. However after the value the datatype is given in URI. I need only the value. 2) Is there a way to get an English label for the other object URIs. Something of them would be meaningfull to be displayed. @AKSW

Comment: Your query does not have a filter for literals, but a filter that restricts to the English language in case of string literals. This should be clear if you have a look at your triples, which also contain URIs in object position, e.g. `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/ManchesterUnitedF.C.Players`

Comment: you can call `if(o.isLiteral()){System.out.println(o.asLiteral().getLexicalForm());} else {System.out.println(o);}`

Comment: Even if I add a literal it will still return the result with datatypes which is again in URIs. My purpose here is to get the objects of two RDF and display common objects in a graph or other visualization method. @AKSW

Comment: What is wrong with my suggestion to print the lexical form? if you have a literal `"31.0"^^<http://dbpedia.org/datatype/perCent>` it will only print `31.0`.

Comment: Is there a way to get similar labels for URIs? For example http://schema.org/Person is an object And does this type of URIs have a label which is readable like "Person". So one of the object of Cristiano Ronaldo would be "Person" other than "http://schema.org/Person". I hope you got my point. @AKSW

Comment: @AKSW: For example if you do a dbpedia lookup http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=Cristiano. As you can see each URI has an appropriate label with it. Can we get a label similar to that for every object which is a URI?

Comment: Then you simply have to get the label via SPARQL. Just append a triple pattern that optionally gets the label: `OPTIONAL{?o rdfs:label ?label . langMatches(lang(?label),'en')}` and indeed add this triple pattern to the CONSTRUCT clause.

Comment: This is my query --- "CONSTRUCT {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Karim_Benzema> ?p ?o} where {"
    + "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Karim_Benzema> ?p ?o BIND(datatype(?o) as ?dt) FILTER(IF(isliteral(?o) && !bound(?dt), langMatches(lang(?o),'en'), true))" +

  "OPTIONAL{?o rdfs:label ?label . langMatches(lang(?label),'en')}}"; However this gives me an error Encountered " "langmatches" "langMatches "" at line 1, column 757. @AKSW

Comment: Can please print the whole query and post as an update in your questions. It's difficult to see with some concatenated strings.

Comment: @AKSW - Have updated the original post.

Comment: Thank's, but that's not what I mean. Please **print** the string with Java, and post this. It's much better to see the string then code where you concatenate strings.

Comment: Ah, ok. I see the problem. Forgot the FILTER indeed. Should be `OPTIONAL{?o rdfs:label ?label . FILTER(langMatches(lang(?label),'en'))}`

Comment: @AKSW - I have updated the OP with the current java code. As you can see I have added the filter to it properly. However the result i am retrieving are still in URIs.

Comment: I'm not sure if you really understand what SPARQL does. Of course, you now have triples in your model of type `<subjectURI <predicateURI> <objectURI> `, but in addition you have for `<objectURI>` the label, i.e. a triple `<objectURI> rdfs:label "labelLiteral"`. Obviously, you have to get the label of the model, `if(o.isURIResource()) {//get the label from the model}`

Comment: @AKSW - Thanks fixed it. 'if(o.isURIResource()){listOfString.add(o.asResource().getLocalName());}'

Comment: :D well, that is not what I meant. This way would also work without loading the labels from the SPARQL endpoint. The problem is that it might work DBpedia, yet you still have special characters and/or camel-case style, i.e. you have "Karim_Benzema" instead of "Karim Benzema". As URIs are only identifiers, they do not always have some human language in it. It could also be something like `http://example.org/16a5sa5sda`. That's why best practice is to add labels

Comment: And now I saw that you did not extend the CONSTRUCT part as I told you to do: I'd suggest to read a SPARQL tutorial first. The information that you select in the WHERE part and should be part of the returned model must indeed be put into the CONSTRUCT part. That means, put the `?o rdfs:label ?label` to the CONSTRUCT part.

Comment: And then, instead of using the local name of an arbitrary URI, get the label from the model as I told you. And this is another triple, thus, do something like: `if(o.isURIResource()) {StmtIterator labelsIter = model.listStatements(s, RDFS.label, (RDFNode) null);}` And then do something with the labels (there might be more than one)

Comment: @AKSW - Could you please provide an example? I was trying to to add the label to the model but failed. So I tried it the other way.

Comment: You still did not provide the plain current SPARQL query, not in Java code...that means, call `System.out.println(queryString);` It's weird to test/validate/edit your query if we have always to remove Java characters like `+,"`

Comment: and I meant to add the triple pattern `?o rdfs:label ?label` to the CONSTRUCT part. The part before the WHERE

Comment: @AKSW - Sorry about that. I have added the query to the OP.

Comment: Ok, and now just add the triple pattern to the first part between CONSTRUCT and WHERE. Then you also have the labels (if exist) for the URIs which occur in object position.